# Authenticate websites that are using my service through iframe

Tags: javascript, authentication, iframe

I have a service that I provide to different websites. For the website to use the service they implement a javascript that triggers a lightbox with a iframe in it.

The problem is I don't want any website to be able to use the service/iframe. Is there any way I can authenticate the websites using the iframe?
The way I see it, a random website can just take the javascript from a website using the service/iframe and implement it on it's own website.

Authenticating the actual users inside the iframe is no problem, there will be a login form and a register form. It's just the websites using the iframe I want to identify and authenticate.

Any suggestions is appriciated!

Comment: Take a look at [Sandboxed iframes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) This doesn't answer your question, but is a good to read if you're working with iframes and you're concerned about security issues.

Comment: @nmoliveira Good read, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `document.referrer` in JavaScript, and if the referring domain is not within a whitelist you provide (or the referrer is empty), don't display content at all.

But we all know how unreliable the referrer is, and it might exclude users even under wrong conditions.

Another way would only work it the sites embedding your iframe have server-side scripting and so can calculate some kind of hash - f.e. the hash of the current date and a secret keyword - and pass it as a GET parameter in your iframe URL. In your script, you check if the given value is the same as the hash you create with the same data - and display content based on that or not.

Using the current date could be problematic though if time zone settings for your server and the other site are different, and it might also break when a user calls the page around midnight. To prevent such problems, you could have the remote sites include the unix timestamp value used to create the hash as GET parameter as well - then you can check if that timestamp is not to old, and create the hash with that exact value. (Then other sites might try to just copy the parameters and use them on their page as well, but it will only work for a small time window.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem I see is that a website wanting to use the service could just scrape for the parameters once a day and use the service without paying for it =/

Comment: Like I said, if you make your hash "valid" for a shorter time period only, they would have to scrape more often. But scraping in general can not be avoided with this method.

Comment: True, maybe there is no perfect way of solving it. Maybe the best way to solve it is just by licensing and try to hunt down the freeloaders :P